# ¿Cómo convertir los elementos(String) de un vector en elementos (number)?

Tags: javascript, html

Necesito convertir los elementos de un vector que ingresan como String en elementos numéricos para que después se puedan ordenar de menor a mayor y luego de esto se puedan imprimir en pantalla.

```js
let contenido = document.getElementById("texto");
let button    = document.getElementById("button");
let vector = [];

 button.addEventListener("click", () => {
          let valor = contenido.value.split(",")
          vector.push(valor)
        });


vector.sort(function(a,b){
 return a-b;
 });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Document</title>
 <!--<link rel="stylesheet" href="estilo.css">-->
</head>
<body>
 <h1 id="total"></h1>
 <h1></h1>
 <input type="text" id="texto">
    <button id="button">Crear el vector</button>

 <script src="ca.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDICIÓN Revisa la parte de abajo**

Podemos hacer lo siguiente:

- Declarar una variable `valor` que guarde la iteración de cada elemento del vector que identificaremos como `elemento`
- A cada `elemento` que resulte de la iteración lo pasaremos como argumento del constructor `Number()`
- Llenaremos una nueva variable de tipo `array` con cada `elemento` pasado el constructor `Number`
- Dentro de una variable guardamos la asignación del uso de `sort()` para poder hacer la resta del valor `x` - el valor `y`
- Finalmente imprimimos la variable `ordenado` que contiene nuestro nuevo vector ordenado

---

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
      <title>Ejemplo 1</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <input type="text" id="texto" />
    <button id="button">Crear el vector</button>
    
    <script>
        let contenido = document.getElementById("texto")
        let button    = document.getElementById("button")
        let vector = []
        
        let cambiados = []
        button.addEventListener("click", () => {
          let valor = contenido.value.split(",")
             
          let nuevoVector = valor.forEach((elemento) => {
            cambiados.push(Number(elemento))
            
          })
          let ordenado = cambiados.sort((x, y) => {
            return x - y
          })
          
          console.log(ordenado)
        })
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

**La edición**

Como no me terminaba de cuadrar una *solución tan larga*, comento lo que estuve probando

- El método `split` genera un vector de valores, del input que le llegó como argumento
- Entonces como `valor` ya es un vector solo basta aplicarle la misma función de `sort()` para ordenar los elementos e imprimir el resultado

Aquí esta el código simplificado:

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html>
        <head>
          <meta charset="utf-8">
          <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
          <title>Ejemplo 2</title>
        </head>
        <body>
        <input type="text" id="texto" />
        <button id="button">Crear el vector</button>
        
        <script>
            let contenido = document.getElementById("texto")
            let button    = document.getElementById("button")
            
            button.addEventListener("click", () => {
              let valor = contenido.value.split(",")
                 
              let arreglo = valor.sort((x, y) => {
                return x - y
              })
              
              console.log(arreglo)
            })
        </script>
        </body>
        </html>
```

> Básicamente la diferencia entre el primero y el segundo es que al inicio transformo cada elemento a un tipo `number` y en el segundo lo sigo manejando cada elemento del vector como un `string`

**Referencia**

- [Constructor `Number()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Number)