# ¿Cómo transformar todos los elementos(String) de un array a elementos(Number)?

Tags: javascript, html

Necesito convertir todos los elementos de un array a números, individualmente sé como hacerlo, pongo Number(array[0][0]). Pero no sé cómo se haría el bucle para que se transformara cada elemento del array, luego de que todos los elementos sean números debo hacer unas operaciones con ellos. Tengo un array que contiene arrays, necesito transformar un array que está encapsulado dentro de el array contenedor.
Si pueden me gustaría que me dijeran si hay un método más corto para crear una fila de una tabla, yo lo hice como se ve en el código.
No es nada más, de antemano muchas gracias.

```js
let array1=[];
//------------OBTENER DATOS----------------------------------------
function hola(){
let array2=[];
let n1=document.getElementById('n1').value;
let n2=document.getElementById('n2').value;
let n3=document.getElementById('n3').value;
array2.push(n1,n2,n3);
array1.push(array2);
creacion();
}
//-------------------------------UBICAR DATOS EN CUADRO----------------------------

function creacion(){
 if (array1.length==1) {
 document.getElementById('1').innerHTML=`<td>A</td>`;
 document.getElementById('1').innerHTML+=`<td id="n1_1" class="n1">${array1[0][0]}</td>`;
 document.getElementById('1').innerHTML+=`<td id="" class="n2">${array1[0][1]}</td>`;
 document.getElementById('1').innerHTML+=`<td id="" class="n3">${array1[0][2]}</td>`;
}else if (array1.length==2) {
 document.getElementById('2').innerHTML+=`<td id="" class="">B</td>`;
 document.getElementById('2').innerHTML+=`<td id="" class="n1">${array1[1][0]}</td>`;
 document.getElementById('2').innerHTML+=`<td id="" class="n2">${array1[1][1]}</td>`;
 document.getElementById('2').innerHTML+=`<td id="" class="n3">${array1[1][2]}</td>`;
}else if (array1.length==3) {
 document.getElementById('3').innerHTML+=`<td id="" class="">C</td>`;
 document.getElementById('3').innerHTML+=`<td id="" class="n1">${array1[2][0]}</td>`;
 document.getElementById('3').innerHTML+=`<td id="" class="n2">${array1[2][1]}</td>`;
 document.getElementById('3').innerHTML+=`<td id="" class="n3">${array1[2][2]}</td>`;

}else if (array1.length==4) {
 document.getElementById('4').innerHTML+=`<td id="" class="">D</td>`;
 document.getElementById('4').innerHTML+=`<td id="" class="n1">${array1[3][0]}</td>`;
 document.getElementById('4').innerHTML+=`<td id="" class="n2">${array1[3][1]}</td>`;
 document.getElementById('4').innerHTML+=`<td id="" class="n3">${array1[3][2]}</td>`;

}else if (array1.length==5) {
 document.getElementById('5').innerHTML+=`<td id="" class="">E</td>`;
 document.getElementById('5').innerHTML+=`<td id="" class="n1">${array1[4][0]}</td>`;
 document.getElementById('5').innerHTML+=`<td id="" class="n2">${array1[4][1]}</td>`;
 document.getElementById('5').innerHTML+=`<td id="" class="n3">${array1[4][2]}</td>`;

}else if (array1.length==6) {
 document.getElementById('6').innerHTML+=`<td id="" class="">F</td>`;
 document.getElementById('6').innerHTML+=`<td id="" class="n1">${array1[5][0]}</td>`;
 document.getElementById('6').innerHTML+=`<td id="" class="n2">${array1[5][1]}</td>`;
 document.getElementById('6').innerHTML+=`<td id="" class="n3">${array1[5][2]}</td>`;
}else if (array1.length==7) {
 document.getElementById('7').innerHTML+=`<td id="" class="">G</td>`;
 document.getElementById('7').innerHTML+=`<td id="" class="n1">${array1[6][0]}</td>`;
 document.getElementById('7').innerHTML+=`<td id="" class="n2">${array1[6][1]}</td>`;
 document.getElementById('7').innerHTML+=`<td id="" class="n3">${array1[6][2]}</td>`;
}else if (array1.length==8) {
 document.getElementById('8').innerHTML+=`<td id="" class="">H</td>`;
 document.getElementById('8').innerHTML+=`<td id="" class="n1">${array1[7][0]}</td>`;
 document.getElementById('8').innerHTML+=`<td id="" class="n2">${array1[7][1]}</td>`;
 document.getElementById('8').innerHTML+=`<td id="" class="n3">${array1[7][2]}</td>`;
}
}
//-------------------CONVERTIR A NÚMEROS------------------------------
function suma1(){
 let conver1=[];
 conver1.push(Number(array1[0]));
 console.log(conver1);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Document</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="estilo.css">
</head>
<body>
 <div class="" id="ingreso_1">
  <input type="text" id="n1">
  <input type="text" id="n2">
  <input type="text" id="n3">
  <button onclick="hola();"></button>
 </div>
 <table id="tabla">
  <tr>
   <td>Hola</td>
   <td>Pues</td>
   <td>como</td>
   <td>Numero</td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="1"></tr>
  <tr id="2"></tr>
  <tr id="3"></tr>
  <tr id="4"></tr>
  <tr id="5"></tr>
  <tr id="6"></tr>
  <tr id="7"></tr>
  <tr id="8"></tr>
 </table>
 <button onclick="suma1()"></button>
 <script src="ju.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Posible duplicado de [¿Cómo convertir los elementos(String) de un vector en elementos (number)?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/303241/c%c3%b3mo-convertir-los-elementosstring-de-un-vector-en-elementos-number)

Answer (score 0):

Ya lo conseguí, primero ingresé los datos a un array, estos ingresan como String, luego los convierto en números y los meto en otro array y por último ingreso ese array que ya contiene los elementos como números al array contenedor. Gracias.

```js
let array1=[];
//------------OBTENER DATOS----------------------------------------
function hola(){
let array2=[];
let  array3=[];
let n1=document.getElementById('n1').value;
let n2=document.getElementById('n2').value;
let n3=document.getElementById('n3').value;
array2.push(n1,n2,n3);
let nuevoVector = array2.forEach((elemento) => {
            array3.push(Number(elemento))
          });
array1.push(array3);
creacion();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Esta función te puede servir.

```
function numeroToArray(numeroChain){
    let numero = parseInt(numeroChain);
    let numeroArray = [];
    for (let i = 1; i <= numeroChain.length; i++){
        numeroArray[i-1] = numero - (parseInt(numero/10)*10);
        numero = parseInt(numero / 10);
    } 
    numeroArray.reverse();
    console.log(numeroArray);
}

numeroToArray('15745181');
```

Convierte cualquier string de números en un array de Numbers.
Si alguien me puede ayudar a optimizarlo seria genial.